How to Configure Multiple App Registrations for Tenant-Specific Authentication in a Multi-Tenant ASP.NET Core MVC App?
I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app that uses the Microsoft Identity Platform for authentication and is currently set up as a multi-tenant app registration in Azure. The app filters access based on tenant IDs, and everything works fine with one app registration. Now, I want to extend the functionality to support two different app registrations (for two separate tenants), allowing users from both tenants to authenticate.
Relevant code from my Program.cs:
string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

// Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            string tenantId = context.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "tid" || x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value;

            var allowedTenants = Configuration.GetSection("AllowedTenants").Get<string[]>().ToList();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId) || !allowedTenants.Contains(tenantId))
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unable to get tenantId from token or the tenant is not authorized.");
        };
    })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Configuration from my appsettings.json:
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "******.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "**********",
    "ClientId": "**********",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "ClientCapabilities": [ "cp1" ],
    "ClientSecret": "**********"
},
"AllowedTenants": [ "**********", "**********" ],
"DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "User.Read"
}

My Goal:
I want to allow authentication and access for two different app registrations (each representing a different tenant). The app currently uses a multi-tenant configuration, and I would like to extend this setup to support multiple app registrations, allowing users from both tenants to authenticate.
Key Questions:
How do I configure my AzureAd section in appsettings.json to support multiple app registrations?
What changes are necessary in Program.cs to handle authentication for both tenants, while retaining the tenant filtering functionality?
Additional Info:
I'm using Microsoft Identity Web for ASP.NET Core MVC.
The application is currently a multi-tenant app in Azure.
The app filters access based on the tenantId from the token claims.

Normally in a (multi tenant) app you have to call the Microsoft login page and providing your app ID and the redirect URL. Due to this fact you first have to provide the app ID and then the user enters the credentials. But what you like is to select the app ID by given credentials, which is not possible. What you could do (on your welcome page) is showing some selection option to the user, so she can decide which app to pick for login. After successful login you can store that info in local storage, so the user hasn't to choose again.

thanks for the advice! could you show how you would implement this (controller + view)?

Unfortunately not, sorry. But normally you have a login page in your views. Instead of directly forwarding to Microsoft with a specific app id, you present two links to your users (for each app id one), with some description about which to choose when and each one forwards to Microsoft login with the desired app id. Another approach could be an input field, where the user has to enter its domain and you have some js code that picks the correct app id for the given domain (or an error message).

If your ultimate goal is allowing users from both tenants to authenticate, then using one multi-tenant application is what Microsoft identity platform designed for you. You don't  need to register several single-tenant application for each tenant. Multi-tenant concept is created for this scenario.

You're right. E.g. we have a multi-tenant app registered in multiple customer tenants, but as far as I understood the OP has two multi-tenant apps (with different rights), which should be served by one web-page.

@StanSm789 Could you pls share more about what you want to achieve?

I want my app to work with two tenants, where each company manages its own users independently. My main concern is security. What if someone tampers with the claims?
Also, when the app is registered in one tenant, Entra ID sends an admin consent request to the other tenant when their users try to access the app. Does this pose any security risk if users from unauthorized tenants attempt to access it?
Do you think my current implementation is secure enough?

In that case a normal multi-tenant app is sufficient. Just register it in both tenants and give admin consent to the needed rights in both. To ensure, that your web page doesn't read/write any information from tenant A into/from tenant B is up to your web server. Each authenticated request contains a claims principal. This contains information about the authenticated user including its UPN and tenant id. That should be enough to check that you request the right tenant internally.

Thanks you, @Oliver! I'm still unclear on how the app decides which app registration to use in the first place.
You mentioned that the tenant ID can be passed to the authentication endpoint, but it doesn't quite make sense to me how this maps to a specific app registration. If I have two separate app registrations (one for each tenant), how does the app know which registration to use during authentication?
Is there a specific way to configure the app to dynamically choose between the two app registrations based on the tenant ID? Could you clarify how this decision is made?

You can't pass a tenant ID to the authentication endpoint. You pass the app ID to the authentication endpoint. The user enters his username and Microsoft checks via the user domain, if this app ID has a consent in the tenant. If you have one multi tenant app and it is consented in both tenants everything works as described in the Microsoft docs. If you have two apps in two different tenants, the user has to select before forwarding to Microsoft login the desired app ID somehow.

After app ID (ClientId) is passed to the endpoint, how does the app decide which configuration (app registration) it shall use? I would assume some logic needs to be added into Program.cs. Or a standalone handler should be implemented? This part is unclear to me. Thanks

Also, going back to the code from my question, do you think this implementation is sufficient to safely satisfy the needs of working with two tenants only by filtering them by their TenantId(internal and external client)?
